# App has not been not registered (Expo) Error

Tags: react-native

I have this error, that I can't solve:

[image]

Can someone please help me understand this error.

When I run this app it gives this error however when I start a new project it works fine.

**VERSIONS**

```
 "expo": "~37.0.3",
 "react": "16.9.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

close all the terminal and then open fresh new terminal and start metro by

```
expo start -c
```

Comment: Hey thanks man that worked for me but i get this new error saying "Unable to resolve "./ScreenOrientation/ScreenOrientation" from "node_modules/expo/build/ExpoLazy.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle."